# Bootstrap: Top navigation menu disappears when clicked on

Tags: menu, navigation, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my Twitter Bootstrap website.  When I click on one of the links in the top navigation menu, the rest of the menu items just disappear.

I am using Google chrome.

Any help appreciated!

All the Best,

Daniel

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem over at http://jsfiddle.net? Sounds like a weird issue to diagnose blindly.

Answer (score 1):

I gather this is a known issue that the bootstrap developers say is a Chrome rending issue, not a bootstrap one: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/32